# Google closure compiler application using multiple files and how not to print standard output

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I'm using Google closure compiler application and can't figure out which of the following commands from the help menu would turn off the printing of standard output.

I'm combining multiple js files:

```
compiler-latest TimPeterson$ java -jar compiler.jar --js assets/js/file1.js 
assets/js/file2.js --js_output_file  assets/js/file.min.js
```

*note:* here's the command to access the help menu

```
 compiler-latest TimPeterson$ java -jar compiler.jar --help
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to get rid of?  Are you saying the compilation results are going to standard output (js_output_file doesn't work)?  Or something else?

Comment: @john I'd like to **not** have CC print out the result in my terminal. The result is written to file as I want and that is all I need.

Comment: Something is off then, because when using `--js_output_file` only warnings and errors should be written to the terminal (to standard error).

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth you are right, my standard output isn't being printed when I include the ``--js_output_file`` flag. I misinterpreted the warning as my compiled code b/c it contained such as huge chunk of my compiled code to point out the problem. Feel free to answer this question and I'll accept it or I can answer it too if not interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `--js_output_file` option, the compiler prints warnings and errors to the terminal (to standard error). The compiler should not write anything to standard output in this case.

**Note** that the standard error can include significant portions of the code you'd like to have compiled in its compiled form. This is not standard output though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/knyga/kjscompiler
It compiles js files in project. And watch the dependencies